# Search for string and end when find a keyword

Tags: perl

I see that I have made a lot of people confused. Let me clarify.

I have a log file  called `logdetail.txt`. In this file there are a lot of info. in the log file, each user’s info is stored under `Final Command Run <command>`. Under Each `Final Command` string, There are info that I need to collect, such as User ID, ID status, expiration date……

`logdetail.txt` sample

```
Final Command Run
User ID_1 
Expiration 
Validation Status
More Info 
More info 
Final Command Run
User ID_2
Expiration 
Validation Status
Less info 
Final Command Run
User ID_3
Expiration 
Validation Status
More info
```

I need my output file `logssummary.txt` to show something like this

```
User ID_1, Expiration, Validation
User ID_2,
```

I change the answer below and I added few things but it's not working.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;  
use Data::Dumper;  
my @all; 
my %data = (); 

open (Log_summary,">logsummary.txt");
open (INPUTFILE, "logdetail.txt");

while (%data = <INPUTFILE>) {

    next if /^\s*$/;  # skip empty lines     
    if (/^\s*Final\s*$/) {         
    push @all, { %data };         
    %data = ();         
    next;     
    }    
my ($key, $value) = split /\s*=\s*/, $_, 2;    
trim($key); 
trim($value);     
$data{$key} = $value; 
} 
push @all, { %data } if (%data);  # in case there is no Final at the end  print Dumper \@all;  
sub trim {    
     $_[0] =~ s/^\s+//;    
     $_[0] =~ s/\s+$//;
     }

close(INPUTFILE);

print Log_summary "\nNo more input - exiting\n";
print "\nNo more input - exiting\n";
close Log_summary;    

exit;
```

Comment: Can you edit your explanation, please? I'm finding your question to be a bit unclear as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh, I see... you are saying "at the word *'Begin'*". With the sample input you have, that would mean that you want to skip "User B" information, and only get "user A" and forward?

Comment: Can you reformat your test files? If you indent each line by at least four characters, it'll show up in a grey background. Also please make sure you specify exactly what you're looking for. What is `log.txt` and `result.txt`? Are you parsing one or multiple logs? Is the last line suppose to be `End`? Where's user _StackOverflow_ from?

Comment: Please don't create multiple accounts on the system. If you lose access to one account and end up creating another, please flag for a moderator to help merging your accounts so that you have access to everything.

Answer (score 1):

As near as I can tell, you have records in between lines denoted with "Begin", and you want to be able to access these. This is a simple hack to parse such a file. I am stripping leading and trailing whitespace, and compensating for whitespace in the formatting.

At each Begin, it will dump whatever is in `%data` into `@all` and begin collecting a new set.

If you wish, you can try using the input record separator, `$/` to read complete records at once, instead of reading line-by-line. Not sure that would make things easier.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @all;
my %data = ();
while (<>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;  # skip empty lines
    if (/^\s*Begin\s*$/) {
        push @all, { %data };
        %data = ();
        next;
    }
    my ($key, $value) = split /\s*=\s*/, $_, 2;
    trim($key); trim($value);
    $data{$key} = $value;
}
push @all, { %data } if (%data);  # in case there is no Begin at the end 
print Dumper \@all;

sub trim {
    $_[0] =~ s/^\s+//;
    $_[0] =~ s/\s+$//;
}
```

Comment: I changed the word begin to Final, Here is what I have thus far but it's not working. can you take a look? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

why not just `grep '\(Name|ID\)' yourfile.txt > results.txt`?

Comment: I think that might not work because he wants to only find Name or ID at certain points in the file, so there might be some that fall outside the search. However I could be wrong since I've read the questions 3 times and I'm still not completely sure what he's looking for.

Comment: it's on windows 2003 server, I haver access to perl and batch only. to clear things up.  big Log file that has status info on an ID. I want to output the info that is associated with that id

Comment: Yeah. hard to say. Easy enough to grep for the line number of the first begin, then grep onwards from that point, however.

Comment: @moe: in that case, two simple loops: open file. read/dump lines until you hit a begin. then move on to loop #2 and and read lines and print out the ones that start with ID or Name.

Comment: sounds like this can do it, do you have an example?

Comment: @moe: my perl's very rusty. I've been in PHP purgatory for too long. but hopefully something like this: `open(fh, 'file.txt'); while($line = <fh>) { if ($line =~ /Begin/) { break; }    while($line = <fh>) { if ($line =~ /(Name|ID)/) { .... output here ... }`

Comment: Thank for your prompt response, I’ll try that and report back if any issue